# How to pass a variable from a html form to a .js file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is my code

File external.js:

```
var TRange=null;

function findString (str) {
 if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion)<4) return;
 var strFound;
 if (window.find) {

  // CODE FOR BROWSERS THAT SUPPORT window.find

  strFound=self.find(str);
  if (!strFound) {
   strFound=self.find(str,0,1);
   while (self.find(str,0,1)) continue;
  }
 }
 else if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")!=-1) {

  // EXPLORER-SPECIFIC CODE

  if (TRange!=null) {
   TRange.collapse(false);
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
   if (strFound) TRange.select();
  }
  if (TRange==null || strFound==0) {
   TRange=self.document.body.createTextRange();
   strFound=TRange.findText(str);
   if (strFound) TRange.select();
  }
 }
 else if (navigator.appName=="Opera") {
  alert ("Opera browsers not supported, sorry...")
  return;
 }
 if (!strFound) alert ("String '"+str+"' not found!")
 return;
}
```

File Search.html:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<title>Search</title>
<body>
<form name="input" action = "external.js">
Search for: <input type="text" name="keytext" /><br />
</form>
<p> You can search this text. Search the text again</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I am looking for a method to modify the form part of the HTML file such that it can make a call to the external JavaScript (external.js) and pass the parameters. The parameter will be the text in the input box.

Comment: This is such a basic, fundamental question, that I suggest you do some reading on basic web development with html and javascript.  It will do you a lot more good than trying to piece together stuff like this with Q&A.

Comment: Take @kakridge's advice as constructive criticism. :)

Comment: Thanks @Abhishek.  I think I rushed that comment.  I certainly meant it to be constructive.  I applaud anyone who wants to improve their ability to program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your search.html add a reference to the javascript file. like so

```
<script src="external.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

you can then call functions within the javascript file like so

```
<input type="text" name="keytext" onClick='findString("test")'/>
```

in this example you'd be passing the string "test" to your function findString

Edit: you can use other events like `onblur` as well, it all depends when you want to fire the event.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Basic HTML/javascript: to import an external js file use HTML code : `<script src="external.js"></script>`

Comment: What if we are trying to search the text theuser inputs in the text box: For ex: Search for: <input type="text" id ="keytex" name="keytext" onClick='findString(document.getElementById("keytex").value)'